# Angular 8 and .NET Core Type 'Observable<Profile>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IUser>'

Tags: angular, .net-core, observable

I have application in Angular 8 and .NET Core. My app is generated from template from Visualu Studio, so the authorization is generated too.

```
It has been working great but suddenly I get errors like that, when I started my application:
ERROR in api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:78:29 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Profile' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser'.
  Property 'name' is optional in type 'Profile' but required in type 'IUser'.

78       this.userSubject.next(user.profile);
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:89:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Profile' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser'.

89         this.userSubject.next(user.profile);
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:115:29 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Profile' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser'.

115       this.userSubject.next(user && user.profile);
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:150:42 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SignoutResponse'.

150       return this.success(state && state.data);
                                             ~~~~
api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:195:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Profile>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IUser>'.
  Type 'Profile' is not assignable to type 'IUser'.
```

I remember that I've updated angular material and probably that's all. I don't know why suddenly I get these errors.

Comment: I guess the user object is empty.Can you give the object reference as
user["profile"] instead of user.profile and see if the error still comes

Comment: Modify the Profile class to make name non optional property

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why this class has been changed? By any update? Now I've updated Angular 8 to Angular 9. Class Profile is generated by .net core template from Visual Studio

Comment: And I can't find where is the definition of class Profile

Comment: I've just created another one project from template in Visual Studio - Anuglar and Authentication. And this application is working. Profile is ok. Probably some npm installation changed Profile class but I don't know which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution of my problem:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17919

> @SyntaxWarrior -- i ran into the same problem. I changed it in my
>   package.json but that wasn't enough because it was still being
>   referenced (i assume) through package-lock.json.
>
> The command I ran that fixed it was `npm i oidc-client@1.9.1`
>
> The only problem is that it gave me a whole new giant pile of errors
>   related to 'routerLink'. It looks like there are a handful of places
>   where RouterTestingModule needs to be imported into the
>   api-authorization specs.

The problem was with package oidc-client. In version 1.10.1 is Profile.
I had to downgrade to version 1.9.1 and now it works.